# Create Object at Runtime

Tags: javascript

I have a simple factory below that I would like to simplify and not be required to modify each time I add a new object that I would like to return.  In Javascript, how would I be able to create an object at runtime? Thanks

```
switch (leagueId) {
  case 'NCAAF' :
      return new NCAAFScoreGrid();
  case 'MLB' :
      return new MLBScoreGrid();
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly saying "at runtime"? The only time objects are created is at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var leagues = {
    'NCAAF': NCAAFScoreGrid,
    'MLB':   MLBScoreGrid,
    // ...
};  // maybe hoist this dictionary out to somewhere shared

if (leagues[leagueId]) {
    return new leagues[leagueId]();
}
// else leagueId unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bracket operator to look-up the constructor.

```
new (window[leagueId + 'ScoreGrid'])(...);
```

Comment: I wish this worked as this seems to be the cleanest solution, but unfortunately I am using Javascript in an embedded TV environment and there is no root window object.

Answer (score -2):

you can use eval method for example,

return eval("new "+leagueId+"ScoreGrid();");

eval will evaluate code at runtime and will return the object.

Comment: I am actually developing using a TV framework that prevents the use of eval.

Comment: eval is evil and should be avoided.